# disco audio power save problem

Tags: drivers, sound, suspend, 19.04

I did a fresh install of 19.04, and when the audio driver has nothing to send to the speakers, it drives me nuts by a loud 50 Hz (?) buzz from the speakers that are connected to the earphone outlet. When there is something to be played, everything is fine, but as soon as the audio stream stops, it starts to buzz and it is better to unplug the speakers.
The problem showed up already in 18.10, but only during shutdown or suspend, which is bearable. In 19.04 it is far, far worse.
I work on an ACER Aspire V15 Nitro, connected to 230V / 50Hz, as do external my speakers. The laptop is on a master power outlet, the peripherals (monitor, speakers) on slave outlets.

How do I stop the loud buzzing or prevent the driver to enter power save mode? Otherwise I have to abandon this release and revert to 18.04.

Tia, Theo

Comment: Is it a dual booted laptop? If so, did you observe similar problem from Windows 10?

Comment: Yes it is. No I didn't, but I seldomly boot into Win10.

Answer (score -1):

I edited 2 or 3 files as described in stoneage posts, and the first one of them seems to work. 
 - from https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1897012 anno 2011 the
   line "options snd-hda-intel power-save=0" added to
   /etc/modprobe.d/alsabase.conf

---

FORGET THE REST
 - from the same https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1897012 in /usr/lib/pm-utils/intel-audio-powerave the line INTEL_AUDIO_POWRERSAVE=false The latter seems to be a typo in the filename, so it won't do the job.
 - in /etc/default/tlp the lines SOUND_POWER_SAVE_ON_AC=0 and SOUND_POWER_SAVE_ON_BAT=0

Comment: For a good answer you should settle for the one approach that works.